# Is there a way to read and write using the same FileChannel?

Tags: java, nio, filechannel

I am new to Java NIO. I am seeing that a `FileChannel` object has both read and write methods. But I am unable to read and write using the same `FileChannel` at a single point of time. Is there a way to do so?

Comment: Unless you tell the problems you have faces in doing. It is difficult to answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Get a `FileChannel` from RandomAccessFile object with "rw" mode.

```
RandomAccessFile aFile     = new RandomAccessFile("abc.txt", "rw");
FileChannel      inChannel = aFile.getChannel();
```

You can refer  this link for more.
[FileChannel tutorial](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-nio/file-channel.html)

Answer (score 0):

If you obtain the `FileChannel` from a `RandomAccessFile` opened in "rw" mode you can both read and write. In all other cases you can't.